# QML: How to call method from a C++ subclass?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have two C++ classes (TrafficLight and Light).  Light is a child of TrafficLight.  `QML` can see everything from TrafficLight and nothing from Light, for example...I get the following error when I try to access a method from Light like `TrafficLight.get_light(0).get_color()`

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'get_color' of undefined
```

I exposed my parent class (TrafficLight) to qml (see main below). I assumed it would expose the subclass inside it, as well...but apparently not.

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "traffic_light.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    Traffic_Light traffic_light;

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("TrafficLight", &traffic_light);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

My question is how would I expose the subclass?  I can't just create an instance of Light and expose it the same way I did TrafficLight.  Reason being is it won't be the same Light that's inside the TrafficLight. :(

**light.h**

```
#ifndef LIGHT_H
#define LIGHT_H

#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>

enum Color
{
    RED = 0,
    YELLOW,
    GREEN
};

class Light : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Light();
public slots:
    void set_color(Color color);
    int get_color();
    void set_light(bool is_on);
    bool get_light();
private:
    Color m_color;
    bool m_light_on;
};

#endif // LIGHT_H
```

**traffic_light.h**

```
#ifndef TRAFFIC_LIGHT_H
#define TRAFFIC_LIGHT_H

#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>
#include "light.h"

class Traffic_Light : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Traffic_Light();

public slots:
    Light &get_light(int index);
    void toggle_light(int index);

private:
    Light m_light[3];
};
#endif // TRAFFIC_LIGHT_H
```

Comment: You should show also the declaration of both `Light` and `TrafficLight`.

Comment: get_color is defined as a slot not a public function.

Comment: @Pemdas, It still gives me the same error.  Maybe I misunderstand slots, but I thought slots are the only things Qml sees.

Comment: Traffic_Light::get_light should return a `Light*`. Defining it as a slot should work with QML, declaring it as Q_INVOKABLE instead would also make it accessible from QML though. Then you should register Light with QML (qmlRegisterType and friends) and use Q_PROPERTY for Light::color and Light::light instead of slots, to make QML bindings work.